# Redimensionar Carousel Bootstrap 3

Tags: html5, bootstrap, bootstrap-carousel

Hola tengo un carousel de bootstrap y me gustaría modificar su tamaño pero no logro hacerlo, e intentado aplicar modificaciones a la clase principal pero solo consigo reducir el tamaño del carrusel en si no de las imágenes del carrusel ¿como establezco un tamaño personalizado?

Código del carrusel:

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <!-- Indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
    </ol>

    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
      <div class="item active">
        <img src="img/paso1.png" alt="Facebook" class="img-responsive">
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <img src="img/paso2.png" alt="Geolocalisacion" class="img-responsive">
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <img src="img/paso3.png" alt="Pedir" class="img-responsive">
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <img src="img/paso4.png" alt="Recibir" class="img-responsive">
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Left and right controls -->
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
  </div>
```

trate de modificar el tamaño de "myCarousel" y esto no influye en el tamaño de las fotos, y al intentar modificar el tamaño de las fotos porcentualmente tampoco ocurre nada.

Comment: Hola Cristofer, ¿Podrías añadir más información a la Pregunta? _"Qué has intentado"_, como, código de ejemplo.  De esta manera se te podrá brindar una mejor respuesta.

Comment: mete el carrusel en una tabla y listo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El CSS de Carousel tiene `height` puesto en `.carousel` y `.carousel-inner > .item > img`.  Hay que cambiar los dos:

```
.carousel, .carousel-inner > .item > img {
  height: 100px;
}
```

Aquí hay un ejemplo: https://jsfiddle.net/cedfkkn6/

Otro ejemplo con valores solamente porcentuales (son relativos al contenedor): https://jsfiddle.net/cedfkkn6/1/

Comment: genial gracias :)

Answer (score 3):

Intenta con `carousel-inner img` para darle tamaño a la imagen y `carousel-inner` para darle tamaño al carousel como tal, observa:

**CSS**

```css
.carousel-inner img {
    width: 100%;
    max-height: 460px;
}

.carousel-inner{
 height: 200px;
}
```

```html
**HTML**  

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="col-xs-6 col-xs-offset-3 tamano" >
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <!-- Indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
    </ol>

    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
      <div class="item active">
        <img src="http://unsplash.s3.amazonaws.com/batch%209/barcelona-boardwalk.jpg" alt="Facebook" class="img-responsive">
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <img src="http://unsplash.s3.amazonaws.com/batch%209/barcelona-boardwalk.jpg" alt="Geolocalisacion" class="img-responsive">
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <img src="http://unsplash.s3.amazonaws.com/batch%209/barcelona-boardwalk.jpg" alt="Pedir" class="img-responsive">
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <img src="http://unsplash.s3.amazonaws.com/batch%209/barcelona-boardwalk.jpg" alt="Recibir" class="img-responsive">
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Left and right controls -->
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
  </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Esta respuesta me funciono en bootstrap 4... la anterior no